# C# with Outlook...adding signature to an RTFBody email instead of an HTMLBody

Tags: c#, outlook, signature

I have an email being generated by C# using Outlook Interop but I need to use RTFBody as it is RTF formatted, and not HTMLBody, which is where I see all the examples of being able to add the signatures in there.

I am attempting to do something similar but this is no working for me.  Any advice to get this working in Outlook 2016?

```
MyOutlook.Mailitem oMailItem =(MyOutlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(MyOutlook.olItemType.olMailItem);
oMailItem.Display(oMailItem); //create the empty mail item
oMailItem.To = emailform.ToMain;
oMailItem.CC = ccStrings;
oMailItem.BCC = emailForm.BCC;
oMailItem.Subject = emailForm.Subject;
oMailItem.RTFBody = GetRTBText(); //function to get RTF byte array

private byte[] GetRTBText() {
   Clipboard.Clear();
   RTBBody.SelectAll();
   RTBBody.Copy();
   return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf));

}
```

UPDATE:

So it looks like I can get the signature to display when I do the similar trick to oMail.HTMLBody with the omail.RTFBody and concatentate something with it.  The problem now is that the original item doesn't display because it says you can't add byte[]. I either need to override the + operator for this instance or figure out how to add an empty byte arr to it...

So I've tried to concatenate the byte array being returned with an empty byte array. Throws an out of memory exception.  I've tried to concatenate with the oMailItem.RTFBody email item itself, same issue...

not sure what else to do...when I do this, even though it throws an error, the Signature appears, just the body of the email doesn't.

Comment: When you say it's not working, are you receiving an error message, or is something else happening?

Comment: The email opens and everything populates but no signature shows up.

Comment: Is it possible to see what `GetRTBText()` does?

Comment: @MartinParkin Yes, I posted the code for it...basically it just encodes the data from the Rich Text Box into a byte array and returns it.

Comment: It's a stupid question maybe, but are you setting the mail format to RTF? `oMailItem.BodyFormat = olFormatRichText`

Comment: I am not..Should I be? @MartinParkin I added it but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can read RTF body into a hidden RTF control, load the RTF signature file data, then insert it into the RTF control - I used `EM_EXSETSEL` / `EM_STREAMIN` (`SF_RTF | SFF_SELECTION`) Windows API messages for that. You can then stream the resulting RTF out.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured a workaround way to do this by displaying the email so the signature would show, then taking the HTMLBody of the mailItem, and putting it into a webbrowser document instance, and then copying and pasting that to the Rich Text Box, and then encoding the rich text box text into a byte array in the RTFBody.

It works to put the proper information in there but without proper fonts and colors.  If there is another way to use the actual HTMLBody instead I would like to know how...